# HTML/CSS floating sidebar, but normal behavior at top of page

Tags: css, html

I am working on a web page ([link](http://www.slushie.me/test/display.php?articleID=102)) whose layout has a header on top, across the entire page, and then underneath two side-by-side sections, `div.content` and `div.sidebar`.

While the viewers are scrolling down, I want the sidebar to remain at the top of the page (i.e., a floating sidebar).

When using `position:fixed` in css, it works fine, except at the top of the page, where the sidebar overlaps with the header.

If I use a `top:200px`, it goes under the header, but when people are scrolling, the sidebar stays lowered.

Is it possible to have the sidebar behave regularly when the user is at the top of the page, so the sidebar doesn't interfere with the header, but have the sidebar float at theh top (`top:0px`, for example) when the user is scrolling and the header is off the screen?

Comment: I'm afraid you would need Javascript to achieve this as you found only want to give the menu div a fixed position when it hits the top of the page. [Here is a tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/) that will produce [this effect](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Awesome, thanks. That's exactly what I wanted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `div.sidebar`:

```
position: fixed;
top: 200px;
right: 20px; /* change this if you want */
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just works for when the header is visible. When you scroll down past the header, the sidebar is still shifted downwards. Can I make it so that it's shifted downwards when the header is in the way, but when the header is not visible (ie when the viewer scrolls down) it goes to the top of the screen?